# Execute remote jar file (hosted webserver)

Tags: java, android, class, jar, remote-access

I've been trying to call a method's class in a jar file, hosted in my website. The jar file does exists and it's called remotelly in plain Java successfuly.

I have an ClassNotFoundException exception calling it in Android:

```
...
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... credenciais) {
    String dexDirectory = context.getDir("dex", 0).getAbsolutePath();
    ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
    DexClassLoader loader = new DexClassLoader("https://www.mywebsite.com/file.jar!/", dexDirectory, null, parent);
    Class c = null;
    try {
        c = loader.loadClass("package.ClassName");
        Object o = c.newInstance();
        Method m = c.getMethod("func");
        m.invoke(o);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
...
```

Stack:

```
10-13 12:05:40.937    6182-6206/com.company.project W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.ClassName
10-13 12:05:40.945    6182-6206/com.company.project W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
...
```

Comment: I doubt `DexClassLoader` will handle an SSL tunneling for you.

Comment: What if it was just http:// ?

Comment: I don't think so, but why don't you try it and see by yourself?

Comment: It doesn't work. Unless i made it wrong ...

Comment: Looks like logical, I think you can only load local JARs

Comment: Oh btw, I was unable to dynamically load a JAR in Android. You need to convert it to DEX (using ´dx´ tool) or APK (compiling as usual).

Comment: I will try to download the jar file to the SDCard and then load it ...

Comment: Note my last comment: you **can't** load a JAR in Android, you need to process it first with `dx` tool, or use an APK.